# upload file to mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I've really been stuggeling to get my head around the issue I have.
I've looked the whole internet but couldn't find any reason why I keep having this issue.

My file does get sent to the 'uploads' file on my server, but the details don't get sent to mysql db. What am I doing wrong?

Index.php

```
    <?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class='container'>
    <label for='voornaam' >Naam*: </label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='voornaam' />
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
    </form>
    <br /><br />

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
if($_FILES["file"]["error"]>0)
{
    echo "FILE ERROR";
    die();
}
$filename = "uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
// move file to a folder
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filename))
 {
  $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(name, file) VALUES('voornaam',$filename')";
  mysql_query($sql);
  ?>
  <script>
  alert('successfully uploaded');
        window.location.href='index.php?success';
        </script>
  <?php
 }
 else
 {
  ?>
  <script>
  alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='index.php?fail';
        </script>
  <?php
 }
?>
```

Comment: Can you dump out the error that MySQL is reporting (assuming there is one)? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Edit: Also of note, those `mysql` drivers have gone the way of the dodo bird: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: missing a single quote from around filename in the sql - `VALUES('voornaam',$filename')` should be `VALUES('voornaam','$filename')` ~ but better to use prepared statement and stop using `mysql_*` it is deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: @ChrisSprague, there are not errors

Comment: And how do I get the "text" out of the field "voornaam"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly Drop using `Mysql_*` functions those are deprecated use
  prepared statements instead

here's the solution
upload.php

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
if($_FILES["file"]["error"]>0)
{
    echo "FILE ERROR";
    die();
}
$filename = "uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
// move file to a folder
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $filename))
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(name, file) VALUES('voornaam','$filename')";
    mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    ?>
    <script>
        alert('successfully uploaded');
        window.location.href='index.php?success';
    </script>
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    <script>
        alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='index.php?fail';
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

dbconfig.php

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'tbl_uploads');
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, and how do I get the input form the "voornaam" field in my database?

Comment: $val=$_POST['voornaam']; $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(name, file) VALUES('$val','$filename')";

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please read about PDO / MYSQLI.

About your problem, you have to remove '

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I sure will read about PDO/MYSQLI but I'm a newbe so please be understanding. Also, how do I get the text form the input box "voornaam" into my db?